# How to link 2 php scripts to run simultaneously in d3

Tags: php, d3.js

I have two php scripts both connected to the same database but each script queries a different table. My question is how do I link these scripts so they run simultaneously. Currently they are running at the same time but completely independent of each other. For example I am working with a scatter plot in d3. One script queries information for the y axis and the other script for the x axis. This is the query in the php script for the x axis:

```
$myquery = "SELECT  `ID`, `TITLE`, `YEAR`, `In_library` FROM  `papers` where In_library = 1";
```

YEAR is then called in d3 and used to scale the x axis. The query for the y axis script is:

```
$myquery = "SELECT `ID_to`, count(*) as `counter` from `citations` group by `ID_to`";
```

counter is called by d3 and used as the y axis. 
These are the connections made in d3:

```
d3.json("connection1.php", function(error, data){
if (error) throw error;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d['TITLE'] = d.TITLE.toString();
    d['YEAR'] = +d['YEAR']; 
     console.log(d['YEAR']);
    })
d3.json("connection2.php", function(error, data){
//if (error) throw error;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d['counter'] = +d['counter'];
    console.log(d);
    })
```

when ran exactly as above it will just return the points correctly in regards to counter but on top of the y axis with no x values(ie x=0). But when I separate the 2 functions as in close the parentheses from the first line of each function and define all other code ie. svg, domain range etc in BOTH functions they will both execute but mutually exclusive ie. the points displayed are duplicated - one set only with y values and the other set only with x values.

My mission is to integrate these so only one set of the specified points are displayed on the graph using both the x and y axis properly.
I would be grateful for any feedback and happy to post more of the code if I havent posted enough. thanks

EDIT: 
Here is my php script:

```
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="samplelit";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

   $myquery = "SELECT  `ID`, `TITLE`, `YEAR`,`In_library` FROM  `papers` where In_library = 1";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);


?>
```

And the other script is the same with just the other query. Where do I assign the key value pairs? Thanks for the help I am very new to php and appreciate this a lot!

Comment: While @Cyril's recommendation below would allow you to call both php scripts concurrently, it sounds like you want to combine them into 1 script that executes both queries and returns the result together.  Additional HTTP calls and the expense of connecting to your database are expensive.  Making one call that uses the connection twice is not.

Comment: @Mark yes I what I want to do is what you described above. How would I combine them into one script? Would I have another script combining them or how do I query them both and return the results together?

Comment: This is really a `php` question, not a `d3` or `JavaScript` one.  Essentially, you just open the connection, execute query1 and query2 and store the results in a key, value pair array `array(result1 => query1Results, result2 => query2Results)`, serialize this to `JSON` and return it.  Update your question with your `php` and I'll try to help, I'll warn you though, I'm not a `php` programmer.

Comment: @Mark I have just posted my php above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer, I'm not a php developer and the below code is untested...*

This should be as simple as:

```
<?php

$username = "root"; 
$password = "";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="samplelit";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

// this is your return
$data = array(
    query1Results => array(),
    query2Results => array(),
);

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT  `ID`, `TITLE`, `YEAR`,`In_library` FROM  `papers` where In_library = 1");

if ( ! $query1 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query1); $x++) {
    $data['query1Results'][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
}

$query2 = mysql_query("SQL FOR SECOND QUERY");

if ( ! $query2 ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query2); $x++) {
    $data['query2Results'][] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);

?>
```

Now back on the JavaScript side:

```
d3.json("connection.php", function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    // do stuff with results
    console.log(data.query1Results);
    console.log(data.query2Results);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make the 2 ajax calls return @ same time.

But you can use [d3 queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) to send two calls and then get the result(of all the calls) in one success block like this.

*1st include this js in your html*

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
```

*2nd you can do the following to club the two Ajax calls to return result in single success function.*

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "connection1.php")
.defer(d3.json, "connection2.php")
.await(makeChart);//here on success of two calls call the function

   function makeChart(error, connection1_data1, connection2_data2) {//first param is error and not data
      console.log(connection1_data1);//connection1_data1
      console.log(connection2_data2);//connection2_data2
      console.log("everything ran");
     };
```

Hope this helps!